# How do the visions happen when Itami hits his head on EP.1?

Tags: gate

In episode 1(5:15) Itami hits his head and while on the floor he sees the 3 girls he is going to hang out with in the future. But how does he see that? 
Is it something the Rory did, or Lelei or Tuka? Or is it something else?

https://youtu.be/_ZMVaU89xLQ

Answer (score 1):

It is not known if he really saw them or if it was a flash shown only to the viewers. Itami never acted on these visions, not did he mention them or even showed any *deja vu* towards the girls.

My bet is on the **something else** hypothesis:

1:

> The gate main function is to bring different species into the special region. It is revealed when they visit the wizard's cities, and the grand master delivers her report to Ruri.

2:
There are gods in the world of Gate, and several of them are very powerful. Rori is a (probably old) demigod, you can put the gods' powers a level of magnitude above Rori's.

From 1) and 2), we can speculate that:

> some deity linked the gate to Japan, for some undisclosed purpose. That same deity could have sensed Itami and sent these visions to him, to guide his path.